# Escaping spaces in paths for use in batch file

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, ogr

I am making a MapInfo program in MapBasic. I am calling OGR2OGR in order to convert some files. To do this I am generating a batch file and then running it. My code looks something like this:

```
RunStr = "OGR2OGR -f ""ESRI Shapefile"" """ & ExportFolder & "SHP\"" """ & TableFileName & """ -overwrite -skiperrors"
SHPMaker = ExportFolder & "SHPMaker.bat"

Open File SHPMaker
  For Output
  Access Write
  As #1
Print #1, RunStr
Close File #1

Run Program SHPMaker
```

My problem is that ExportFolder and TableFileName can potentially include spaces. My questions is **how should I go about escaping spaces?** I have tried both adding carets (^) before the spaces and putting double quotes around the paths -neither works.

The error I am getting is "Unable to open datasource 'GIS' with the following drivers", followed by a list of available drivers. Obviously it is picking up the "GIS" part from mid-way through the paths and treating it as the data source as you can see below.

The generated BAT file looks something like this:

```
OGR2OGR -f "ESRI Shapefile" "S:\000 GIS Files\TEST WORKSPACE 2\convert test\Converted\SHP\" "S:\000 GIS Files\TEST WORKSPACE\SiteForm.TAB" -overwrite -skiperrors
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if it's because the output.shp hasn't been constructed properly?

Check to see that the output is formatted fully - ie; ends in **output.shp**

Try changing:

```
OGR2OGR -f "ESRI Shapefile" "S:\000 GIS Files\TEST WORKSPACE 2\convert test\Converted\SHP\" "S:\000 GIS Files\TEST WORKSPACE\SiteForm.TAB" -overwrite -skiperrors
```

to...

```
OGR2OGR -f "ESRI Shapefile" "S:\000 GIS Files\TEST WORKSPACE 2\convert test\Converted\SHP\output.shp" "S:\000 GIS Files\TEST WORKSPACE\SiteForm.TAB" -overwrite -skiperrors
```

Comment: That works! It's odd though. I could swear it was giving me errors when I had it that way before.